# Access to local data from an android webview

Tags: android, html, file, webview

I am trying to load a local javascript file from a webview. 
The file "search.js" is located under the assets folder in my project.
I used this line to load my webpage :

```
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", data, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

on my webpage, I am using this line :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="search.js"></script>
```

to load my javascript file.

When I run the program, I just get a white page..............

I don't know what to do. Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/yourfile.html");
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: change the order of above two statements as well :)